# How to install plugins for VIM?

Tags: powershell, vim

I have microsoft windows 7 and powershell.

Everytime I add commands to powershell (those commands written by those who created those plugins), it says it doesn't recognize anything.

Anyway, imagine I freshly installed VIM, How do I install a plugin for example:

https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree

Thanks btw! Please please please write it in newbie terms. I'm really new to all this!

Comment: I'm unclear on how Vim plugins relate to PowerShell. If you have not had success with extending either of those programs, you should post separate questions about them.

Comment: If you are looking for a plugin manager for gvim then go directly for pathogen. Vundle is another option but setting it up for windows is really a tough job and even after i did everything required, i had a lot of issues with it. Pathogen is the easiest and fastest way to go!

Answer (score 13):

I'm a big fan of [vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle). There's a quick start available on the github page but here are some basic steps for windows.

## Step 1: Find your home directory

Vim stores it's configuration files in a "home" directory. On windows this location will vary but one of the easiest ways to locate your home directory is to open vim and type `:echo $HOME`. Vim will print the home directory which is where our configuration files need to live.

## Step 2: Set up vimfiles and _vimrc

There are two major components to configuring vim. The first is a `_vimrc` file which is a plain text file that contains configuration settings. The second is a `vimfiles`folder which contains plugins and other useful vim things. Both of these files belong in your **HOME** directory which we located in the previous step.

Sometimes in tutorials you will see references to `.vim` and `.vimrc` these are the Linux/Unix/MacOSX equivalents to `vimfiles` and `_vimrc`. These files will also work on windows but are more difficult to create as windows explorer won't let you create files or folders that begin with a dot.

To create a `_vimrc` simply create a file named `_vimrc` using `Right Rlick>New>Text Document`. Make sure your `_vimrc` file doesn't have the .txt extension. You can double check this in explorer by looking at the *Type* column. If the type is *File* then you're good to go. If the type is *Text Document* or anything else then you need to [show file extensions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/show-hide-file-name-extensions) and get rid of the extension.

In the same place as your `_vimrc` create a folder named `vimfiles`.

## Step 3: Get git

Git is a source control system and it also allows vundle to automatically manage your plugins for you. You can download it [here](http://git-scm.com/download/win). Make sure to pick "Run Git from the Windows Command Prompt".

## Step 4: Install Vundle

Open PowerShell or command prompt and type:

```
git clone https://github.com/gmarik/vundle.git $HOME\vimfiles\bundle\vundle
```

Make sure to replace $HOME with the path we discovered in step 1.

## Step 5: Set up your _vimrc

Now we need to write your `_vimrc` and decide what plugins you want. Here's an example `_vimrc` that installs nerdtree for you:

```
set nocompatible               " turns off legacy vi mode
filetype off                   " required!

set rtp+=~/vimfiles/bundle/vundle/
call vundle#rc()

Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'         " Use the bundle command to select plugins
Bundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree'   " Bundle automatically searches github for you.

filetype plugin indent on     " required!
```

## Step 6: Let vundle get to work!

Now we're ready to let vundle do it's job. Open vim and type `:BundleInstall` vundle will download and install the plugins you specified in your `_vimrc.`

## Bonus Section

Here's some extra resources that have some really useful information:

- [Vundle Homepage](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle)
- [Vundle for Windows](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle/wiki/Vundle-for-Windows)
- [Information about _vimrc/.vimrc location](https://superuser.com/questions/86246/where-should-the-vimrc-file-be-located-on-windows-7)

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I needed! I never knew I had to install Git :/

Answer (score 2):

Vim8 has made this super easy.

From Vim version 8 onwards, vim came up with native pack system.
You just need to clone the git repo into your `~/.vim/pack/vendor/start/` directory

You can name any name to the `vendor` directory.

More on this: https://medium.com/@paulodiovani/installing-vim-8-plugins-with-the-native-pack-system-39b71c351fea

Answer (score 1):

I use `vim-pathogen`

> `pathogen.vim` makes it super easy to install plugins and runtime
>   files in their own private directories.
>
> Installation
>
> Install to ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim. Or copy and paste:
>
> mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload ~/.vim/bundle; \ curl -Sso
>   ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim \
>       https://raw.github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/master/autoload/pathogen.vim
>
> If you're using Windows, change all occurrences of ~/.vim to
>   ~\vimfiles.
>
> Runtime Path Manipulation
>
> Add this to your vimrc:
>
> execute pathogen#infect()
>
> If you're brand new to Vim and lacking a vimrc, vim ~/.vimrc and paste
>   in the following super-minimal example:
>
> execute pathogen#infect() syntax on filetype plugin indent on
>
> Now any plugins you wish to install can be extracted to a subdirectory
>   under ~/.vim/bundle, and they will be added to the 'runtimepath'.
>   Observe:
>
> cd ~/.vim/bundle git clone git://github.com/tpope/vim-sensible.git
>
> Now sensible.vim is installed.

Download it at [vim-pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen)

Answer (score 0):

On windows, you must put your settings and mappings in the file `_vimrc` located in your `$HOME` directory and your plugins and colorschemes in the `vimfiles` directory located at the same place. These directories probably don't exist so you must create them.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle), It's awesome for vim plugin management.